# I want that when the mouse is over one option in my dropdownlist, the background color of the option value on my second mask must be changed

Tags: jquery

I have 2 dialog mask on my window.

On the fist one I have a drop-down list with different option values.

On the second I have a div table.

I want that when the mouse is over one option in my drop-down list, the background color of the option value on my second mask must be changed and when I leave the background color be restored to white, so that I can know the corresponded feet and meter's value before i selected.

Please look at the screenshot

Comment: You didn't include any screenshot.

Comment: Please post some example code, too.

Comment: @tine You can edit your question to include a screenshot and some code.

Comment: What is a "mask" on a window?

Comment: @Peter Nothing, what's a-maska with you?

Comment: @bzlm - Is that supposed to make sense? or are you obtusely saying that the OP makes no sense?

Comment: @Peter You got it. :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/476120/tine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but try it

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //standard mouseover on a list or another set of elements
                $("ul>li").mouseover(function(){
                    cls = $(this).attr("class");
                    $("td." + cls).addClass("hilite")
                }).mouseout(function(){

                    $("td." + cls).removeClass("hilite")
                })



                //this is for when you select something from a select box
                $("select").change(function(){
                    $("td." + cls).removeClass("hilite")
                    cls = $(this).val();
                    $("td." + cls).addClass("hilite")
                })
                /*
                 //this only works in firefox

                 $("option").mouseover(function(){
                 cls = $(this).val();
                 $("td." + cls).addClass("hilite")
                 }).mouseout(function(){

                 $("td." + cls).removeClass("hilite")
                 })
                 */
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .hilite {
                background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <div>
            <select>
                <option value="opt">Option 1</option>
                <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
            </select>

            <ul>
            <li class="opt">
                Option 1
            </li>
            <li class = "opt2">
                Option 2
            </li>
            <li class="opt3">
                Option 3
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="opt">
                    Option 1
                </td>
                <td class="opt2">
                    Option 2
                </td>
                <td class="opt3">
                    Option 3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```